# DynamoDB: Retrieving the n most recent items for each user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a `DynamoDB` table that store information about images. The hash key is a unique string that identifies each image. There are also two global secondary indicies: *username* and *creation date*. Username belongs to the user who created the image.

For each user, I want to be able to show them their 10 most recent images. How can I retrieve items from the table by first identifying images associated with a particular username, then choosing 10 of them by sorting through the creation dates?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. That way, you can let future StackOverflowers know that it can work for them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this query, you need a GSI with a hash key of `userId` and a sort key of `creationDate`.

You can then do a query for a specific userId, set [`ScanIndexForward`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ScanIndexForward) to `false`, and set [`Limit`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-Limit) to `n`.